# Trialforce TMO and TSO expiration dates

Tags: org, trialforce

just a simple question, cant seem to find straight answer,
How long TMO and TSO last ? Do they even expire ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently experienced our TSO expiring, and the org had even been fully removed already so no recovery possible. We didn't log in for about 6 months and as far as I know we didn't receive any communication about it expiring..

So they definitely expire. You can check the SF licenses on your Company Information page on Setup and mark those expiry days in your calendar.